# How to put a specific account as default value on Lookup(Account) data type?

Tags: lookup, data-types

I don't know why this kind of option is not available on lookup field in Salesforce .

What I need is to retrieve some  information details from a specific account .

Is there another way to proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you say more about what you need to retrieve? It sounds like populating the lookup is a means to an end here, and knowing the end might open up other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you've not properly configured the Search Layouts for either the Account Object or the Object that you want to do the lookup to the Account Record from in Setup as shown in the screen capture below.

[image: Account Search Layouts Screen Capture]

Properly configuring these layouts is essential if you want contextual search features to work properly in your applications. That requires them to be configured for both the object you're searching from and the object you're searching for.